# vue svgIcon converting fill to _fill

Tags: svg, vuejs2

The actual file is this

```
<path pid="1" opacity=".991" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#d39f86" d="M877.5.../>
```

Compiled file is this

```
<path pid="1" opacity=".991" fill-rule="evenodd" _fill="#d39f86" d="M877.5.../>
```

Now the whole SVG is rendered as black in the browser.How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this issue, but this is one of the first results from searching in Google and still has no answer so I'll do it -

Their idea is to make the color configurable via the `fill` attribute so that you can attach that to JS variables and make them dynamic. But if you just want whatever's defined inside the svg file, the `original` attribute determines whether or not to use the svg's original fill attributes.

So when you're using it in Vue, just do this:

```
<svgicon name="icon" :original="true" />
```